# ScrollView hides bottom Linear Layout

Tags: android, button, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have the following XML layout in my android application, using ScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView.../>


<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <CheckBox ...>
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>    
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox ..></CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:text="Block Type:" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<RadioGroup android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/inputType" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btCall" android:paddingRight="10px" android:text="Call" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:checked="true"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btSMS" android:paddingRight="10px" android:text="SMS" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/btBoth" android:paddingRight="10px" android:text="Call + SMS" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
<Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/chooseContactButton" android:text="Choose from contacts..."></Button>

<TextView android:text="Name:" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPersonName" android:id="@+id/inputName">d</EditText>

<TextView android:text="Number:" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="phone" android:id="@+id/inputNumber"></EditText>

<TextView android:text="SMS to send:" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<EditText android:text="I'm busy right now." android:inputType="textMultiLine" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minLines="3" android:enabled="false" android:id="@+id/inputMsg"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView> 

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/okButton" android:text="Save" android:width="150px" android:visibility="gone"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/updateButton" android:text="Update" android:width="150px" android:visibility="gone"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/removeButton" android:text="Remove" android:width="150px" android:visibility="gone"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cancelButton" android:text="Cancel" android:width="150px"></Button>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Views above ScrollView freeze fine & the view scrolls good enough.
The problem is that the LinearLayout containing Buttons is thrown off the view. It cannot be seen.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the ScrollView, try changing `android:layout_height` to `"fill_parent"` adding `android:layout_weight="1"`.

This should make the ScrollView set its height to the gap between your set of buttons and the other views above it.

Also, try not to set the height of the ScrollView to "wrap_content", it doesn't make sense as the whole point of it is to scroll through content (within a fixed height).

Comment: Yup, changing the layout_weight fixed it. I had to set the weights of lower button group too. I figured that out while googling just 2 days ago. Thanks, marking it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Relative Layout and set the last linear layout (linearLayout2) as parent bottom and scroll view above this linear layout.

Comment: It was too flexible for my current need. Thanks.