# LinearLayout dissapear in ScrollView android

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView`, this is my outline's layout:

```
      <ScrollView >
        <Linear Layout>
            <Linear Layout>
            <EditText/></Linear Layout>

            <Linear Layout>
            <EditText/></Linear Layout>

            <Linear Layout>
            <EditText/></Linear Layout>
            ............................................
            ............................................
            ............................................
            ............................................
            ............................................
            ............................................ //and many Views Here
            <Linear Layout>
            <Button/></Linear Layout>
        </Linear Layout>
      </ScrollView>
```

When I Run my Application with empty content in `EditText` or Spinner, The last `LinearLayout` that contain `Button` is displayed, But when I fill `EditText` or add another content The last `LinearLayout` that contain `Button` it shouldn't scroll anywhere and obviously not disappear. I've following the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187579/scrollview-makes-bottom-views-disappear-in-a-dialog) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641836/scrollview-hides-bottom-linear-layout) with adding `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height:"fill_parent"` in 'ScrollView` but It seems doesn't work, is there another solution for my problem? thank you.

Comment: why is every EditText inside linear layout? what is the use of that linear layout if it holds only one child view?

Comment: it would really help to get the full xml, not just the structure of it.

Comment: @pskink that's only my outline's layout example, the truth is my layout more complex than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be another method:

1. Set button over scrollView and add it to xml : android:visibility="gone"
2. Get last scrollView position [How get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609253/how-to-get-last-scroll-view-position-scrollview)
3. When scroll to the end: button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)